# kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined occurred when tested with iOS 6.1 simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mapkit

all.

Recently I am stuck with this error. Here is my codes

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){

    NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled");

    // Switch through the possible location
    // authorization states
    switch([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]){
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            NSLog(@"We have access to location services");
            [self loadAnnotations];
            MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.04, 0.04);
            MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(locationManager.location.coordinate, span);
            [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            NSLog(@"Location services denied by user");
            [self loadAnnotations];
            [_mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            NSLog(@"Parental controls restrict location services");
            [self loadAnnotations];
            [_mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            NSLog(@"Unable to determine, possibly not available");
            [_mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
            [self repeatCheckLocation];
    }
}
else{
    // locationServicesEnabled was set to NO
    NSLog(@"Location Services Are Disabled");
    [self loadAnnotations];
    [_mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
}
```

This is for a location app that calls some places around the user. It is working on other versions but 6.1. Whenever I run my codes on iOS 6.1 simulator I see it stops at kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined. The weird thing is.. it works while running on my testing device which is iOS 6.1 installed iphone4. I have no idea what when wrong..
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It may be an old question, but someone else may find it useful:

> There is no way for the Simulator to get the current location as your
>   computer doesn’t have GPS built-in (even you have, Xcode won’t use
>   it). However, the Simulator allows you to fake it.
>
> ......
>
> By default, the Simulator doesn’t know its own location. In the menu
>   bar, select “Debug” -> “Location”. The default location is set to
>   “None”. Now change the location setting to “Apple” (or “Apple Stores”).

Check [here](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/).